# InteractiveTradingChart not working inside Dynamic

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I would like to have an interactive trading chart that updates by changing the input stock. But anytime a dynamic is wrapped around the function, it doesn't manage to initialize. Is there any way to go around this ?

A basic example is below.

```
Dynamic@InteractiveTradingChart[{"GOOGL", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}}]
```